# APS Design Automation : Can resulting datasets be shared among workitems

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm looking for an answer for following situation : I have an root model that consists out of 50 unique subassemblies. Each subassembly is a configuration on its own. So I have to configure each subassembly with its own parameters, activity and dataset. This would mean I have to upload the dataset for each subassembly to its own bucket and run a workitem to configure this ? After running these 50 workitems, I have 50 configured results waiting in APS to be downloaded. What I can do is download these results  and upload them again to another bucket to start assembling them all into my root assembly following there own rules defined in its appbundle.
Is this the way to go or can I share the results created by WI 1.. WI 50 by WI 51 ? This would mean that I can skip the download and upload of a lot of assemblies.

TIA,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to download and upload. When you POST WI 51 you could specify the outputs of WI 1..50 as inputs.

Albert

Comment: Albert, Thanks for the reply. Maybe you could indicate on how to specify to use the output of WI1 as input for WI51 ?

Comment: The WIs have arguments. Each argument may have an URL which will be used to upload/download the data for the argument (depending on the "verb"). These URLs can point to anywhere (APS, AWS S3, Azure Blob Storage, OneDrive, SharePoint etc.) So if you have a WI that has an output argument "out1" like so:
...
"out1" : { "url" : "http://someserver.com/somefile.ext", "verb" : "put"}
...
Then a subsequent WI may have an input argument "input1" like so:
...
"input1" : { "url" : "http://someserver.com/somefile.ext", "verb" : "get"}
...
someserver.com may want you to specify "headers" too.

Comment: Albert, That was the missing piece I was looking for. Thanks !