# How to use websockets on server for Design Automation workitems progress messages?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Is it possible to use Design Automation WebSocket api for getting workitem processing statuses when workitems are submitted by the server side application running on a single instance using two-legged auth token? Basically, what if server side code sends two or more 'post-workitem' messages, will the websocket api return initial status messages using FIFO order?

Preliminary tests indicate that it is the case that initial status messages will be returned using FIFO order. However, does the API guarantees this? Of course, it would be the best if we could provide some identifier in 'post-workitem' message which would be returned in status messages.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and recommended way over polling, the each `workitem` submitted is queued and processed.

Comment: And, you also can use output url of your first workitem as input url for second workitem. 
 See [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75149118/aps-design-automation-can-resulting-datasets-be-shared-among-workitems?rq=2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it would be the best if we could provide some identifier in 'post-workitem' message which would be returned in status messages

Indeed, this exists but I see our documentation fails to mention it. It is called `conversationId`. If you specify it next to `action` then it will be passed back to you. The value of `conversationId` must satisfy the following regex: `^[\w]{1,40}$`